# what is the Laravel code for fetching all records from table where my JSON datatype column is null?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
 Coupon::whereJsonContains('products_applicable',['1'])->get();
```

I have tried this,it will return all the records having value 1 in the product_applicable json column.
I want to fetch  all records having null value in product_applicable json column.

Comment: have you tried ```Coupon::whereJsonContains('products_applicable',[null])->get();```

Comment: yes not getting any record matching null value

Comment: Is `products_applicable` `nullable`? If yes, you should be able to use `Coupon::whereNull('products_applicable')->get();`

Comment: Thanks ,Coupon::whereNull('products_applicable')->get();
it worked

Comment: how do we fetch record using a variable? like $request instead value 1??

Answer (score 0):

**Is products_applicable nullable? If yes, you should be able to use**

```
 Coupon::whereNull('products_applicable')->get();
```